# Unable to host ASP.NET MVC 4 app using mod_mono

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, mono, debian, mod-mono

I'm trying to host an ASP.NET MVC 4 application in apache with mod_mono but I keep getting the following error:

```
An exception has occurred while generating HttpException page:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
at System.Web.Util.HttpEncoder.GetCustomEncoderFromConfig () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Lazy`1[System.Web.Util.HttpEncoder].InitValue () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0

The actual exception which was being reported was:
System.Web.HttpException: Initial exception ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Error deserializing configuration section httpRuntime: Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. (/var/www/nishkriya/Web.config line 1)
at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSection.DeserializeSection (System.Xml.XmlReader reader) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Configuration.Configuration.GetSectionInstance (System.Configuration.SectionInfo config, Boolean createDefaultInstance) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSectionCollection.get_Item (System.String name) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Configuration.Configuration.GetSection (System.String path) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.GetSection (System.String sectionName, System.String path, System.Web.HttpContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.GetSection (System.String sectionName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at System.Web.HttpRuntime..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

I compiled mono and mod_mono from source.

```
root@inez ~# mono --version
Mono JIT compiler version 3.0.7 ((no/514fcd7 Thu Mar 21 22:55:42 GMT 2013)
Copyright (C) 2002-2012 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
    TLS:           __thread
    SIGSEGV:       altstack
    Notifications: epoll
    Architecture:  amd64
    Disabled:      none
    Misc:          softdebug
    LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
    GC:            Included Boehm (with typed GC and Parallel Mark)
```

The application is set to use /usr/local/bin/mod_mono_server4 which points to

```
exec /usr/local/bin/mono $MONO_OPTIONS "/usr/local/lib/mono/4.5/mod-mono-server4.exe" "$@"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This smells like a bad installation. Do you have another mono installed in /usr/bin (besides /usr/local/bin)? If yes, then you should wipe your box and start again, but this time looking at this [guide](http://www.mono-project.com/Parallel_Mono_Environments).

Answer (score 0):

you can try another asp.net web server on mono Jexus http://linuxdot.net, It support  ASP.NET MVC 4 application